# Reset identity column with last value of table's identity in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I would like to changes my existing column as Auto Identity in a Postgres Database. 
I used below script to set auto identity column and set default start with 1.
But here i would like to reset identity column value to table's last value. 
Let me know if you have any solutions.

```
ALTER TABLE patient 
    ALTER patientid SET NOT NULL,
    ALTER patientid ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1);
```

Here I'm setting up something like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE Patient 
   ALTER COLUMN PatientId RESTART WITH (select Max(patientId) + 1 from patient);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An identity columns is also backed by a sequence, and `pg_get_serial_sequence()` will return that sequence name. That can be used together with `setval()`.

After running the `add generated always` part you can adjust the sequence using this statement:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('patient', 'patientid'), 
                                      (select max(patientid) from patient));
```

Comment: That solution i already know. but i don't want to use serial.here i would like to use identity as describe in a question.

Comment: @NayanRudani: as I wrote in my answer: an `identity` column also uses a sequence. The above code **will** work for `identity` columns just as well.

Comment: I got it. Thanks